# Handling the requirement using regular expression

Tags: regex

See the below xml file. The $BASE_DIR, $ENV_PREFIX etc., are environment variables in a linux OS. I want to find the variables of the format $followed by any letter then any letter or number till < symbol where the tag is closed and store those in a list. Please note the ones where ${envPrefix} are replaced later on by a 3rd party api and should be ignored in this list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myconfig.xsd">

    <configVariable name="baseDir" type="java.lang.String">
        <value>$BASE_DIR</value>
    </configVariable>

    <configVariable name="envPrefix" type="java.lang.String">
        <value>$ENV_PREFIX</value>
    </configVariable>

    <configVariable name="logPath" type="java.lang.String">
        <value>${baseDir}/${envPrefix}</value>
    </configVariable>

    <configVariable name="appName">
        <value>Publish</value>
    </configVariable>

    <configVariable name="CUSTOM_LOG">
        <value>$CUSTOM_LOG</value>
    </configVariable>

    <configVariable name="PUBLISH_LOG">
        <value>$PUBLISH_LOG</value>
    </configVariable>

    <logging>
        <destination type="file" maxFileBackup="16" maxFileSize="10MB"
            filePath="${PUBLISH_LOG}/${appName}.log" smLogName="publish" />
        <priority level="info" smLogName="publish" />
    </logging>

    .......

</myConfig>



String fileContent="the_file_provided_above";

            List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("????What goes here">)).matcher(fileContent);
            while (m.find()) {
                allMatches.add(m.group());
            }
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out the regular expression that needs to go here, I am not sure on what goes after $ to handle this. I tried something like below just to get it working...  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("$ENV_PREFIX")).matcher(fileContent);
  while (m.find()) {
   allMatches.add(m.group());
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this as your regular expression:

`<value>(\$\w+)<\/value>`

This will match a literal `$`, followed by at least one word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _). By matching word characters after the `$` we can avoid matching the `${...}` elements, since `\w` will not match `{`.

Comment: Perfect! It suits my requirement. Thanks. Used   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<value>(\\$[a-zA-Z]\\w*)<\\/value>").matcher(fileContent);

Comment: Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<value>(\\$[a-zA-Z]\\w*)<\\/value>").matcher(fileContent);
  while (m.find()) {
   String group = m.group();
   allMatches.add(group.substring(7, group.length() - 8));
  }